# MySQL time calculation when

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one (personal_work) where I record working time of the employee, another table where I store how much which employee earn per hour depending on the working time. 
A employee can have depending on the working time various hour rates.

Is it possible to get the result trough a query within MySQL?

Will the table work_our work as is or I must take take time_to is never == time_from from another record for the same employee?

personal_work

```
id | work_date  | time_from | time_to  | personal_id
 1 | 2017-01-01 | 16:00:00  | 22:00:00 | 3
 2 | 2017-01-01 | 11:00:00  | 12:00:00 | 6
 3 | 2017-01-01 | 15:00:00  | 02:00:00 | 10
 4 | 2017-01-01 | 20:00:00  | 00:00:00 | 12
```

work_hour

```
id | personal_id | valid_date_from | valid_date_to | time_from | time_to  | amount
 1 |           3 | 2013-01-01      |          null | 07:00:00  | 23:00:00 | 5.55
 2 |           3 | 2013-01-01      |          null | 23:00:00  | 07:00:00 | 7.77
 3 |           6 | 2013-01-01      |          null | 07:00:00  | 23:00:00 | 8.88
 4 |           6 | 2013-01-01      |          null | 23:00:00  | 07:00:00 | 5.55
 5 |          10 | 2013-01-01      |          null | 07:00:00  | 23:00:00 | 7.00
 6 |          10 | 2013-01-01      |          null | 23:00:00  | 07:00:00 | 10.00
 7 |          12 | 2013-01-01      |          null | 07:00:00  | 23:00:00 | 4.56
 8 |          12 | 2013-01-01      |          null | 23:00:00  | 07:00:00 | 7.89
```

result

```
personal_id | period_from         | period_to           | paid
          3 | 2017-01-01 07:00:00 | 2017-02-01 06:59:59 | 33.30
          6 | 2017-01-01 07:00:00 | 2017-02-01 06:59:59 | 8.88
         10 | 2017-01-01 07:00:00 | 2017-02-01 06:59:59 | 86.00
         12 | 2017-01-01 07:00:00 | 2017-02-01 06:59:59 | 21.57
```

Comment: 1) work_hour: why id is always 1?

2) "Will the table work_our work as is or I must take take time_to is never == time_from from another record for the same employee?": explain better this question, it is not clear.

3) in personal_work, also add another example of row having personal_id 3 and also change the results according to that (will you have two records in results having personal_id 3?)

Comment: Personal_id 6 should have earned 8.88 ;)

Comment: @Eugenio was a fault by me, it should be different

Comment: @JanZeiseweis you're right, I should sleep more :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ignore the valid_date_from and valid_date_to, you can use this:

```
SELECT lo1.personal_id,

       ROUND(SUM((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(lo1.end_datetime, lo1.start_datetime))/3600 - 
       TIME_TO_SEC(IF(lo1.start_datetime < lo2.start_datetime,TIMEDIFF(lo2.start_datetime, lo1.start_datetime),0))/3600 -
       TIME_TO_SEC(IF(lo1.end_datetime > lo2.end_datetime,TIMEDIFF(lo1.end_datetime, lo2.end_datetime),0))/3600) * amount), 2) AS to_pay
FROM
    (SELECT personal_id,
            ADDTIME(work_date, time_from) AS start_datetime,
            ADDTIME(IF(time_to > time_from, work_date, work_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY), time_to) AS end_datetime
     FROM personal_work) AS lo1
JOIN
    (SELECT personal_id,
            ADDTIME(work_date, time_from) AS start_datetime,
            ADDTIME(IF(time_to > time_from, work_date, work_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY), time_to) AS end_datetime,
            amount
     FROM
         (SELECT DISTINCT work_date
          FROM personal_work
          UNION SELECT max(work_date) + interval 1 DAY
          FROM personal_work AS work_date) AS dates_table
     JOIN work_hour) AS lo2 ON lo1.personal_id = lo2.personal_id
AND (lo1.start_datetime BETWEEN lo2.start_datetime AND lo2.end_datetime
     OR lo1.end_datetime BETWEEN lo2.start_datetime AND lo2.end_datetime)
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: great solution it does what I need and is better then my actual one where PHP is involved.

Comment: You're welcome. If you look at the subqueries, you'll see that  I created two intermediate tables. If you look at them you'll see that I `only` changed the data structure slightly. It might make sense to change the tables in that way. This would allow you to reduce the query quite a lot.